# Can't store tags with question: string given

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I want to store tags with question in my project, and the relation between question and tags is many to many polymorphic (poly because I have another tables and they have tags field too)

In my **`QuestionController()`**, when I want to store a question and tags, I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given

When I use `save` instead of `saveMany()` gives this error:

> "message": "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given

I also used `sync()`, but tags aren't stored in the database.

I tasted it with postman.

And the `method` is this:

```
 public function store(StoreQuestionRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->all();

      ////Because there is no need storage images and question codes

        $question = Question::create($validatedData); //store question

        //store tags
        $tag = new Tag();

        $tags = explode(",", $request->tag);//separate tags

        $tag['tag'] = $tags;

        $question->tags()->saveMany($tags);

        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'message'=> 'successfully',
            'data'=>$question
        ]);
    }
```

So if you need to know about `relations`, these are my models:

**`Question`**:

```
 public function tags(){
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
```

**`Tag`**:

```
 public function questions(){
        return $this->morphedByMany(Question::class, 'taggable');
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `$questions->tags()->save($tag)`? You're saving the array, not the `Tag` instance you created.

Comment: when i try `$questions->tags()->save($tag)` gives this error : `"message": Array to string conversion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved :

```
 public function store(StoreQuestionRequest $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->all();

      ////Because there is no need storage images and question codes

        $question = Question::create($validatedData); //store question

        //store tags

       $tagNames = explode(",", $request->tag);//separate tags

        $tagIds = [];

        foreach($tagNames as $tagName)
        {
            $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['tag'=>$tagName]);
            if($tag)
            {
              $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
            }
        }
        $question->tags()->sync($tagIds);


        return response()->json([
            'success'=>true,
            'message'=> 'successfully',
            'data'=>$question
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `attach()` but you need to pass the ids of the tags, not the tags themselves.

if the user just choose between tags you can send the id's of the tags he chose as an array along with the question in the request and then pass it to attach method

```
$question->tags()->attach($request->tagsIds);
```

if the user creates the tags you can collect the new id's and pass them to the attach like so

```
 $tags = explode(",", $request->tag);//separate tags
$tagsIds = [];
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
 array_push($tagsIds,Tag::create(['theTagColumn ex: name'=>$tag])->id);
}
$question->tags()->attach($tagsIds);
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: If the `Tag` does not exist, the [`save` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) is appropriate. Also, `attach` will accept either the record's ID, or the model instance.

Comment: I don't think the save method applies to many-to-many relations,
so using save here is not going to work

Comment: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::create() must be of the type array, string given`

Comment: oh sorry! it should be like so: `Tag::create(['theTagColumn ex: name',=>$tag])`

Comment: and sorry for the late reply

Comment: i have error again `General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{\"tag\":\"ddddd\",\"id\":3}' for column 'stack_tag_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `stack_taggables` (`stack_tag_id`, `stack_taggable_id`, `stack_taggable_type`) values ({\"tag\":\"ddddd\",\"id\":3}, 18, App\\Models\\StackQuestion))`

Comment: good for you, it's my approach but with better syntax * that doesn't throw exception :'D*